# Best practice to store a operation hours in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to design a schema in mongoose to store operation hour for shop, the UI in admincp will be like this:

[image: working hour]

As you can see the first column is working day, owner of the shop can turn on/off if they want. The second is the opening hour and the last one is closing hour.

The schema also need to have default value "off" or "false" for Sat and Sun as almost every shops close on these days.

I am not sure how to design a schema like this in mongoose.

This is what i come up:

```
working: {
    mon: {
      enable: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      start: {
        type: Number
      },
      end: {
        type: Number
      }
    },
    tue: /* and so on */

  }
```

It looks bad, there must be better way to do it.

Comment: ... and how do you plan to _query_ the DB ? By shop ? By hour ? By day ?

Comment: without information about how the information will be read and written (updated) it's almost impossible to know what the best option would be.

Comment: For now the only need for this is how to render like the UI.

I also edit the question and add current db in firebase. The problem is  I need to re-implement that for mongo  and get stuck with the schema.